# How to parse json-file with spring batch?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-batch

I have a list of serialized entities written to a file in json format.
I need to read them from the file using spring batch (then process them and write to DB).

I found only Flat file, DB and Xml readers provided with spring batch.
What's the right way to parse json?

The approach I'm going to implement is:

```
1. read the whole file with FlatFile reader
2. parse it with Jaxson in `read` method
```

I'm completely newbie in spring batch, so I need a piece of advice here. Is this approach correct? Doesn't it violates any spring-batch principles? Or should I use another one?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach would work but I suggest you to use [Jackson Streaming API](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonStreamingApi) to directly parse the JSON file, instead of having an additional step to read the whole file and then process it.

```
JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JsonFactory();
JsonParser jp = jsonFactory.createJsonParser(file);
```

Comment: @Roman to add to this answer, you really don't want to read an entire file into memory for any reason.  Benoit's approach is much more preferred because it keeps memory usage low.  As you become more familiar with Spring Batch, you'll be able to write your own JSON ItemReader and maybe even contribute it back to the project.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `JsonItemReader` in Spring Batch. In my case, I passed the JSON file name as `JobParameter`.

Sample JSON content in my JSON file.

```
{ 
   "obj1": "abc", 
   "obj2": "def" 
}
```

MyObj Class:

```
@Data
@Builder
public class MyObject{
    String obj1;
    String obj2;
}
```

And here is my reader.

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public JsonItemReader<MyObj> myReader() {

    LOGGER.info(LOG_TEMPLATE,
            getClass().getSimpleName(),
            Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName(),
            "Inside Reader...");

    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    final JacksonJsonObjectReader<MyObj> jsonObjectReader = new JacksonJsonObjectReader<>(
            MyObj.class);
    jsonObjectReader.setMapper(mapper);

    final String filePath = config.getRootfolder() + SEPERATOR + inputInfo.getFileName();

    return new JsonItemReaderBuilder<MyObj>().jsonObjectReader(jsonObjectReader)
            .resource(new FileSystemResource(filePath))
            .name("myReader")
            .build();

}
```